# how to align a div between a position absolute and relative

Tags: css, html, position, alignment, center

I have 3 divs. First div is at the top with position relative, and the second div is at the bottom and its position is absolute. There is also a third div which i want it to be on the middle.  I want the third div to be in the middle so that no matter i change the height of my browser, i want it to be alligned with 20px padding, depending on the first and second.

```
middle-box{
padding: 20px;
}

.top-box{
width: 265px;
position: relative;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.bottom-box{
width: 25%;
padding: 12px 0 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
min-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be tricky because position:absolute; doesn't reserve its original space on the page so you wouldn't really know how high it is, but im sure its possible, good luck

Comment: What does "alligned with 20px spacing" mean?

Comment: i want the middle div to have a 20px margin top and margin bottom, according to the other two divs. so the height of the div is not important, but i want it to have 20px gap between the top and bottom div.

Answer (score 0):

Variations on this same question have been asked dozens of times on SO. The fact that you want 20px margin is irrelevant. It's the overall structure that can be tricky.

I think this meets your requirements. The one compromise you may have to make is setting fixed heights on your header and footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fd6f9/1

```
.top-box {
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
.middle-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.bottom-box {
    height: 56px;
    padding: 12px 0 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to have your bottom-box "stuck" to the bottom of the browser window, you'll have a variable space between your middle-box and the bottom-box, depending on how much content is in the middle-box and the size your viewer's browser window. If you want consistent spacing between the divs, you need to remove the absolute positioning.

Also, I'd strongly recommend changing your css from classes to ids (. to #). You forgot the class/id marker on middle-box, so that might also be causing a problem.

Keep in mind that padding will affect the inside of your div, while margin will affect the outside.

Does this code give you what you're looking for? (I added background-colors just for a visual so I could see what was happening to the divs.)

```
<style type="text/css">
#top-box {
    width: 265px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
#middle-box{
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #AAA;
}
#bottom-box{
    width: 25%;
    padding: 12px 0 12px;
    bottom: 0px;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: #888;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-box">something in the top goes here</div>
<div id="middle-box">something in the middle here.</div>
<div id="bottom-box">something at the bottom.</div>
</body>
```

It's hard to know what else to tell you without knowing what you're planning on doing with these divs. Hope this helps!